# Python program to convert excel file to csv, issue in date column from excel

Tags: python

I am new to python and uising below code to convert excel file to csv

### Code is

```
#!/bin/env python
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(file1):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file1)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')
    csv1 = open('test.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csv1,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
        wr.writerow([unicode(entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum)])
    csv1.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

---

But column from excel with below values

```
Case    Code    Date    Amount
5428165773  UA02    4/23/2014    $(1,626.00)
```

showing as

```
'Case','Code','Date','Amount'
'5428165773','UA02',,'41752.0','-1626.0'
```

I also tried adding this but it didn't helped

```
dialect='excel', quotechar="'"
```

Comment: Check out the xldate_as_tuple function. This might help translate Excel's 'number of days since 1900' to something more meaningful. This Stackoverflow post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108428/how-do-i-read-a-date-in-excel-format-in-python

Comment: Not a dupe (as it's Java) but the same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028192/converting-number-representation-of-date-in-excel-to-date-in-java (Excel storing dates as numbers)

Comment: thanks Alex, i am trying rewriting my code with use xldate_as_tuple function

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses a floating point number that represents the amount of days since a fixed date.  You can use the `datetime` module to calculate the date and create a string.

```
import datetime

exceldate = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)

d = exceldate + datetime.timedelta(days=41752)

print d
```

datetime.date(2014, 4, 23)

```
new_date = '{}/{}/{}'.format(d.month, d.day, d.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already installed pandas module,
These code will read excel file and store as dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
xls = read_excel('path_to_file.xls')
```

Then

```
xls.to_csv('path_to_csv.csv')
```

will write dataframe into CSV

you can read more about this in,

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/io.html#io-excel

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/io.html#io-store-in-csv

Answer (score 0):

I think the following function is what you need and it also deals with datetime.time:

```
def xldate_to_python_date(value):
    """
    convert xl date to python date
    """
    date_tuple = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(value, 0)
    ret = None
    if date_tuple == (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0):
        ret = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    elif date_tuple[0:3] == (0, 0, 0):
        ret = datetime.time(date_tuple[3],
                            date_tuple[4],
                            date_tuple[5])
    elif date_tuple[3:6] == (0, 0, 0):
        ret = datetime.date(date_tuple[0],
                            date_tuple[1],
                            date_tuple[2])
    return ret
```

Here is the documentation of [xldate_as_tuple](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.xldate_as_tuple-function). The above function is referenced from [here](https://github.com/chfw/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/io/xlbook.py#L17)

And by the way, your csv_from_excel function can be rewritten as the following if you use my library `pyexcel`:

```
import pyexcel

def csv_from_excel(file1):
    excel_file = pyexcel.Reader(file1)
    csv_file = pyexcel.Writer("test.csv")
    csv_file.write_reader(excel_file)
    csv_file.close()
```

More documentation can be found on [read-the-docs](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks chfw
i tried installing pyexcel and then executing suggested code
    import pyexcel
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyexcel-0.0.5-py2.6.egg/pyexcel/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .readers import Reader, BookReader, Book
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyexcel-0.0.5-py2.6.egg/pyexcel/readers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .iterators import SheetIterator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyexcel-0.0.5-py2.6.egg/pyexcel/iterators.py", line 10, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six

Comment: @itsavy, Try pip install six to get the missing module. I will check later why six was missed. Six as a dependenncy was specified in setup.py. Did you install pyexcel using pip or you clone it and install from source? Which version of setuptools did you have?

Answer (score 0):

yr, mth, dy, hr, min, sec =xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(entry, 0)

this is solving my problem

Thanks everyone and first of all thanks to Alex for very useful direction , right in first attempt

Updates:
My code looks like this now, but I am stuck at writing row level output

```
#!/bin/env python
import xlrd
import csv
from os import sys

def csv_from_excel(file1):
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file1)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('sheet1')
    csv1 = open('test.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csv1,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
        if rownum > 2:
            i=0
            for entry in worksheet.row_values(rownum):
                i=i+1
                if i==3:
                    yr, mnth, dy, hr, min, sec =xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(entry, 0)
                    print str(mnth)+'/'+str(dy)+'/'+str(yr)
                    #wr.writerow(str(mnth)+'/'+str(dy)+'/'+str(yr))
                else:
                    print entry
                    #wr.writerow(unicode(entry).encode("utf-8"))
    your_csv_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1])
```

Current output
5428165773
UA02
4/23/2014
-1626.0

You would understand i need above output as
5428165773,UA02,4/23/2014,-1626.0

Please comment

Update:
This problem solved as well by using print in for loops, insteas of writerow, since it expects whole row

Thanks