# Convert Excel timestamp to java.sql.date

Tags: java, excel

I am extracting a timestamp out of Excel (2010):

It is displayed as "10.06.2015 14:24". The "internal representation" of excel is "42165.6". Last one is outputted from Excel.

So, for now, I want to parse this timestamp into a Java program like this:

```
double input = 42165.6;
// long myLong = ???
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new java.sql.Date(myLong)));
```

How can I do this in line 2?!

Many thanks for your help!!!

Kind regards

Comment: Use a java.util.Date instead. The java.sql.date is only if you are using a relational database.

Comment: How do you get *input* value? Why isn't it date?

Comment: 42165 is the # of days since the epoch (Jan 1900) and .6 specifies a time 60% of the way through a 24-hour day. But I agree, isn't there a better way of extracting the date from Excel?

Comment: @NickJ: I have to put the date into a database.. So I need it as `java.sql.Date` and not util. :/

Comment: @mrbela My answer modified to include creating a java.sql.Date

Answer (score 2):

Excel stores dates as the number of days since January 1900. This makes it awkward to convert into a Java date (milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970). If you cannot export it in a readable format, you'll need to create a Java Calendar, set it to 1 Jan 1900, and add the number of days.

Here it is:

```
    double excelDate = 42165.6;
    int days = (int) excelDate;  //number of days
    int seconds = (int) ((excelDate-days) * 86400);  //number of seconds in .6 days

    //create calendar set to 01-Jan-1900
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    //Add days and seconds to get required date/time
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days-1);
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);

    //cal.getTime() returns a java.util.Date, print it out...
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

NOTE
A `java.sql.Date` can be created from a `java.util.Date` as follows:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = ....
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get from the excel notation to a `java.sql.Date` is:

```
    double excelInput = 42165.6;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println("---> "
            + sdf.format(new java.sql.Date(
                    (long) ((excelInput - 25569) * 86400 * 1000))));
```

Excel stores a date since 01-01-1900, `java.sql.date` since 01-01-1970. There are exactly 25569 days difference between both dates. The constructor of `java.sql.Date` wants the milliseconds (!) since 01-01-1970, so with "* 86400" we get the seconds and then with (* 1000) the milliseconds.

That's it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Putting 42165.6 in excel and formatting to a date gives the correct date `6/10/15 14:24`.

For me the answers by mrbela and NickJ both gave incorrect answers to the question of 42165.6, `06/10/2015 09:23` and `06/12/2015 03:25`. This seems to be true of most of the examples I've tried.

The solution that worked for me was to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), which is a java API for Microsoft Documents. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028192/converting-number-representation-of-date-in-excel-to-date-in-java) is very similar and had the pointers that led me to poi.

Here is a working code example.

```
double input = 42165.6;
Date date = DateUtil.getJavaDate(input);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(javaDate));
```

which outputs the correct `06/10/2015 14:24`