# change date 5 digits int to date string in java

Tags: java, android, excel

Excel converts dates into 5 digits int so I'm asking for a way to convert this 5 digits int `ex. 43277` to date String `dd-MMM-yy` and how to change it "date String" back to 5 digits int. 
I'm trying to make the app reads and writes from an google spreadsheet.

It's true that a similar question asked here "[Converting Number representation of Date in excel to Date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028192/converting-number-representation-of-date-in-excel-to-date-in-java)" but the code provided did not work or me as it showed `cannot resolve symbol 'DateUtil'` and the i couldnt understand the second answer.

Also I am asking how to convert it back and forth not from int to String only.

Comment: I did search and I did find this answer but when I use the code, studio showed an error cannot resolve symbol 'DateUtil' despite importing "java.text.SimpleDateFormat
java.util.Date"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel’s serialized dates are the number of days since 1/1/1900. In order to figure out the date again, we have to add the serial number worth of days.

Java 8 version

```
  /*

    1900-1-0            0
    1900-1-1            1
    1900-1-2            2
    1900-1-3            3


     */


    int days = 43323;
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1900, 1, 1);
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 11);


    // days to date
    LocalDate date = start.plusDays(days).minusDays(2);

    System.out.println(date);

    // date to days
    long days1 = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, today) + 2;
    System.out.println(days1);
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol ChronoUnit

Comment: @Mustafa this is java 8 version

Comment: I think I have the latest version as I keep it updated all the time, how to check what version have?

Comment: @Mustafa try import `import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;`

Comment: requires API 26 and current min is 19 .. so i changed to 26 but now I wont work on my phone! is there another way to make it work in all devices ...

Comment: @Mustafa Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. Further adapted for early Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project. These projects are named after JSR 310.