# Convert "using excel method" numeric value in date - java

Tags: java, android, excel, date, date-conversion

I have an integer that when I put on Google Sheets, it represents the date 14/10/1911 (integer value is 4305).

I need to do this same conversion in my code using Java. So I'll have an array of integer that goes down by a factor of 1 (like 4305, 4304, 4303...) and I need to convert these integers into date (14/10/1911, 13/10/1911, 12/10/1911...) using the same method that excel/sheets uses.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How you can achieve `4305` from `14/10/1911`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Number representation of Date in excel to Date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028192/converting-number-representation-of-date-in-excel-to-date-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LocalDate msBaseDate = LocalDate.of(1899, Month.DECEMBER, 30);
    int[] integers = { 4305, 4304, 4303 };
    for (int integerValue : integers) {
        LocalDate date = msBaseDate.plusDays(integerValue);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 1911-10-14
> 1911-10-13
> 1911-10-12
> ```

Excel and other Microsoft products and possibly other software too use December 30, 1899, as a base date and represent dates as a count of days since that date. So just add the number to that date. I am using `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.