# I want to read the date value of Excel and save it in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

but An unknown number comes in when run the insert.

This is my Excel data date.
2022-04-03 17:51

This is the value inserted into mysql.
44654.7437

The format of the mysql column is datetime and An error occurs.
(Incorrect datetime value)

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide some of your Code. Otherwise it will be hard to see where your problem is.

Comment: Go step by step. When you read the date from Excel, what class are you using (Date, Calendar, LocalDate, ...?) and does the object contains the value you want? Next check how to write such an object to MySQL.

Comment: I didn't know well. It's my first time posting!
I'm sorry.
I'm trying to modify the writing, but I don't know how to modify it.
I'm sorry it wasn't detailed

Comment: A lot of missing steps, did you save excel as csv file? How did you import (import wizard, load data infile , something else), what ui are you using if any? What role does java play in this , if anything add code. Also please add table definition as text and a sample of your csv file as text.

Comment: Search. How Excel stores dates and times is documented in many places. With a little luck you can even find Java code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

The date is stored in Excel as the number of days after 30/12/1899 00:00:00. The numbers after the decimal point give the time, as part of a whole day.
**NB:** certains versions of Excel use a different start date.

We can multiply this number by the number of seconds in a day (84600) and use `date_add` to generate the date.
In this example the conversion is done in MySQL. To do the conversion in Java see: [Converting number representing a date in Excel to a Java Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028192/converting-number-representing-a-date-in-excel-to-a-java-date-object)

```
select date_add('1899-12-30', interval 44654.7437*86400 second)
```

> ```
> | date_add('1899-12-30', interval 44654.7437*86400 second) |
> | :------------------------------------------------------- |
> | 2022-04-03 17:50:55.680000                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0be8ce3aba97b2365198f932a8f2902b)*c4b9d83134)*